# texture mapping in cylindergeometry in three js

Tags: three.js, fabricjs

I am working on firecrackers printing design on `fabric.js` and `three.js` since quite long time and managed to do objects operation in 2d plane in fabric js and then trying to take that newly exported image from 2d canvas to 3d space in three js in it's cylindergeometry.

[image]

[image]

As we can see canvas is sized as square as per the purple color border but it is clipped inside the cross sectional type shape of cylinder as seen in the image so that it's background and objects can't go beyond that boundary.

However when I try to export canvas image after bringing all of the objects to fabric, it is exporting an image that is not covering entire cylinder geometry because that image is same as the canvas which is clipped as per the shape

So what i do is to clone the canvas and remove clippath of clone and then export image which i am using as texture of cylinder geometry to cover whole cylinder side surface with that.

But the problem is that i am not getting exact position of object(red square as shown in image) as per considering my clipPath and canvas considers object position from it's own left side. Even if red square is quite near to clippath it has been considered as left from canvas to set it;s position on cylinder.and if i don;t remove clippath then i am not able to cover entire cylinder with 2d canvas exported image.

Is there any way to map object's position from clippath(yellow shape only) rather than from square canvas and map it back to cylinder in three js as it would map same as if it was square?

The distance shown in second image by arrow is the main issue I am facing and I am not familiar on how to do any mapping manually on `three.js`. So i have to export square image only.

Since it is very difficult to post all code here for this thing, i would like to get suggestions and ideas only for this mapping part.